# Java Spring Repository delete not working OneToMany Relationship

Tags: java, database, spring, sql-delete, many-to-one

I have an issue with a delete to a Many side of a **ManyToOne** relationship. I've already removed all **CascadeTypes** from the relationship but the issue still remains. The entry won't be removed (only selects are executed and no delete query). I'm trying to delete it through a CRUD repository call to delete. It calls the method and executes successfully but nothing happens.

The relationship goes as follows: *an Activity has an assigned Course, a course can have many activities assigned to it. An Activity has a specific ActivityType.*

The classes are as below.

**Activity**

```
public class Activity implements Item, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id", nullable = false)
    private ActivityType type;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomCourseSerializer.class)
    private Course course;

    ...
}
```

**Course**

```
public class Course implements Item, Serializable {

...

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Activity.class) //cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REMOVE}
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<Activity> activities;

...
}
```

**Activity Type** (has no reference to Activity)

```
public class ActivityType implements Item, Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String name;
...
}
```

Any ideas how can I solve this issue or at least debug it? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `orphanRemoval = true`?

Comment: I've added orphanRemoval to course end and nothing changed. Furthermore this isn't desired behaviour (to delete the course when I delete an activity). Or are you referring  to add it on the Activity part?

Comment: If you want to remove child `Activity` you have to add `@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)` in the `Course` class. And this wont delete your `Course` if an `Activity` is removed.

Comment: I've tried adding ` orphanRemoval = true` but to no result. I still can't delete an Activity.

Comment: Please post some code where you are deleting your `Activity` entities.

Comment: It's a call to a spring data repository abstraction `@Override
    public void remove(Long id) {
        activities.delete(id);
    }`, where activities is the repository and the id is the id of the activity (the id exists, I check it in the controller).

Comment: Actually, I also had an obsolete reference that I forgot about to Activities and that's why it wasn't deleting. `@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)` and `cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE' worked. Thanks. You can post an answer to the question to select it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `orphanRemoval = true` attribute in the `@OneToMany` annotation in your `Course` entity.

```
public class Course implements Item, Serializable {

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Activity.class, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE )
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Activity> activities;

    ...

}
```

Comment: I've also added this `cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REMOVE}` for it to work properly.

Comment: why not add `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`?

Comment: For some reason the CascadeType.PERSIST included in ALL would block the delete from happening. Maybe it is an ORM data context thing, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete reference to `Activity` from `Course`. It seems unnecessary to me

Comment: I deleted the reference to `Activity` from `Course` but it still doesn't work.